# page-break-inside: avoid - not working in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, printing, browser, media-queries

I am using Chrome mostly, and maybe first time I found problem like this. It working in IE, not sure other browsers, but no in Chrome. Any idea or tips?

```
@media print
{
table {page-break-inside:avoid}
}
```

also when just puting into div element

Answer (score 3):

It could be that the parent element of the table element has style:

```
display: flex
```

Then the break-inside doesn’t work.

If you change parent element display style to:

```
display: block
```

Then it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Add display:inline-table to any element that you need to be entire when printing or, in your case to table element

table { display: inline-table;}

Answer (score 0):

Chrome does not support that property. Look at [this table](http://www.webdevout.net/browser-support-css?IE7=on&IE8=on&FX3=on&OP8=on&OP9=on&SF2=on&uas=CUSTOM#support-css2propsprint-pagebreakinside) for more infos on that.

Answer taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045470/page-break-inside-avoid)

Comment: Thank you, but I know that Chrome not supported it, so I asked about tips or ideas.